# Does dygraph assume the independent variables are ordered?

Tags: dygraphs

It seems that the default L/H of the x-axis is determined by the first/last point of the series rather than the min/max.

Is there a way to change this behavior in dygraph?
Is this considered a bug? or should I be sorting?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, data given to dygraphs should be sorted.   Some functionality works without it being sorted, but a number of functions expect the first column to be sorted.  I believe it logs a warning when data is not sorted.